# How to find the radius in a hypersphere given an arc

Tags: differential-geometry

Does anybody know how to calculate the radius in a hypersphere if the arc length is known and the curvature of the arc?

Comment: Homework-like questions should ask about a specific physics concept and show some effort to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. See our meta site for more guidance on how to edit your question to make it better

Answer (score 1):

If by arc you mean a segment of a great circle, the dimension does not matter-it is an arc of a circle. Curvature is the inverse of the radius and you are done without the arc length.